# Coloring the subsections and subsubsections with different colors in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, color

Is there any possibility to color the subsections and subsubsection with any other two colors rather than blue, red and green say ?!. 
[image]

I use

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\geometry{footskip=15pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
filecolor=magenta,      
urlcolor=red,  
}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: It can easily be done with `titletoc`.

Comment: May you clarify more please sir ?. I did not get what you meant @Bernard

Comment: What changes should I do in my preamble ? @Bernard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example blue is the main link colour (`hyperref` option `linkcolor`). You can change the link colour for the ToC entries of different levels:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\geometry{footskip=15pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=green}}% you can replace green by the defined colour you want (see `xcolor` manual)
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}}% you can replace red by the defined colour you want (see `xcolor` manual)

\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true,% switch on coloured instead of framed links
    linkcolor=blue,% main link color (e.g. for the ToC)
    filecolor=magenta,% color of links to external files
    urlcolor=red,% color to external URLs
}                           %

\usepackage{mwe}% for the example only
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

To be true: This is a hack. But it works:

[image: Table of Contents with different link colours]

Answer (score 6):

With `tocloft`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\geometry{footskip=15pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\hypersetup{                  %
pdfborder={0 0 0}             % new code 
}                             %
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\color{green}}     % newcode
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\color{red}}    % newcode
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\hypersetup{                %
    colorlinks=true,        % 
    linkcolor=blue,         % moved after \tableofcontents
    filecolor=magenta,      % 
    urlcolor=red,           %
}                           %

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

I used `\cftXfont` to change the colors and had to defer the hyperlink setup statement after the table of content, so that it does not interfere with `\cftXfont` 
[image]

To change also the color of the dots and the page number add:

```
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\color{green}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecpagefont}{\color{red}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\color{green}\cftdotfill{\cftsubsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{\color{red}\cftdotfill{\cftsubsubsecdotsep}}
```

[image]